# Images are blurry in expression blend during a transition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I am working on a WPF application in expression blend transition between states, the images look like they move a couple of pixels and they look a little blurry. I checked all my states and everything looked fine in them. All the elements are contained in grids and canvases which appear and disappear in the states that I have added. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have any kind of a delay set in the Duration or a specific EasingFunction set on the transition? Beyond that, Michael's answer is quite likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Images have to be 96 dpi to be used properly in Blend so it’s 1:1. This should really be pointed out in the documentation. If the image is not 96dpi then it ends being stretched in Blend and makes the image blurry which is not good."

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd282881.aspx

Comment: My image was 96 dpi but I seemed to have resolved my issue by deleting the image and importing it into expression a second time.

Comment: Great @user1563870. I'm glad your issue was resolved in a simple matter!